# Angular2 equivalent of $document.ready()

Tags: angular

Simple question, I hope.

I want to run a script when the Angular2 equivalent of $document.ready() is fired. What is the best way to achieve this?

I've tried putting the script at the end of `index.html`, but as I found out, this doesn't work! I take it that it has to go in some kind of component declaration?

Is it possible to run load the script from a `.js` file?

EDIT - Code:

I've got the following js and css plugins injected into my application (from the [Foundry html theme](http://themeforest.net/item/foundry-multipurpose-html-variant-page-builder/11562108)).

```
    <link href="css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    ...


    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flexslider.min.js"></script>
    ...
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script> //This initiates all the plugins
```

As noted, the scripts.js 'instantiates' the whole thing, and thus is needed to be run after Angular is ready. [script.js](https://plnkr.co/edit/fp3I6kJu15aGbxMValu3?p=catalogue)

**Got it working:**

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './components/home/home.html'
})
export class HomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {


    ngAfterViewInit() {
       //Copy in all the js code from the script.js. Typescript will complain but it works just fine
    }
```

Comment: after some hours of research, I still got the same issue. > Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@types/jquery' I installed it with npm install --save -D @types/jquery, then when i try to import it in the Module (due to the fact that i got a Message from the toolbox that it doesn't know $ from jQuery) in my Component.ts it says my first message ! I hope my explanations are corrects Thanks again for all the help this community gave to me ! btw : This is my first real message so I hope to write a good one

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can fire an event yourself in `ngOnInit()` of your Angular root component and then listen for this event outside of Angular.

This is Dart code (I don't know TypeScript) but should't be to hard to translate

```
@Component(selector: 'app-element')
@View(
    templateUrl: 'app_element.html',
)
class AppElement implements OnInit {
  ElementRef elementRef;
  AppElement(this.elementRef);

  void ngOnInit() {
    DOM.dispatchEvent(elementRef.nativeElement, new CustomEvent('angular-ready'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, perfect. Could you possibly provide a quick example of such code? Sorry, but quite new to ng2

Comment: Preferably I'd like to be able to load a js file when the onInit occurs. This file has all my document ready code (from a html template I'm using) and is in js, so I can't just copy paste it in since I'm writing ng2 in .ts

Comment: Check the [reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html) for ngOnInit.

Comment: @Boris it doesn't get me very far I'm afraid

Comment: @Chris I see your comment, what is the code, why would it not be possible to load it in onInit?

Comment: Is the code you want to run after ready part of your Angular application or is it supposed to run outside Angular?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added some code and a little explanation above

Comment: As part of your Angular application or outside of Angular. I think you should start with the Angular tutorials at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial

Comment: As part of my angular application

Comment: Then you just run the code in `ngAfterViewInit() { ... }`. No need to fire an event.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you have any idea why this doesn't work in the app.component, but works fine in the component specific to the view? Hope this makes sense

Comment: Actually no. What do you mean by "app.component", the root component? What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is `ngAfterViewInit` not called? Can you please update your question and add your current code?

Answer (score 70):

Copying the answer from Chris:

**Got it working:**

```
import {AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';    

export class HomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {    

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       //Copy in all the js code from the script.js. Typescript will complain but it works just fine
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. This worked for me, but also introduced a race between the legacy JS code I was trying to run and the view compiler. I ended up using `AfterViewChecked`, but all the same, here's an upvote for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This might work but it might not be the best practice. What would be better is have all of the external code wrapped in some global, but well namespaced function, then call this function from `ngAfterViewInit()`.
E.g. `window.MY_APP = {}; MY_APP.init = function () {/*copy all that script.js here*/ }`. Then in your component, `import ...; declare var MY_APP: any; class HomeComponent() { ngAfterViewInit() {  MY_APP.init(); } }`
But the bottom line is still that you don't have an angular2 app - your script.js is basically an old-school jquery page. You could turn most of it into NG2 components.

Comment: I am not downvoting this but in this method I can reach DOM elements. However when I try to get element.css('height') it returns to me 0px Thus I cannot use it for setting css.

Comment: It worked for me perfectly :)  I think, at this stage you have already DOM, but might not have yet all the sources loaded, like images. So it's exactly like `$document.ready()`.

Comment: Sweet and smooth!

Comment: Upvoted this answer because it contains a comment with the actual solution: using  AfterViewChecked

Answer (score 16):

I went with this solution so I didn't have to include my custom js code within the component other than the jQuery **$.getScript** function.

> Note: Has a dependency on jQuery. So you will need jQuery and jQuery typings.

I have found this is a good way to get around custom or vendor js files that do not have typings available that way TypeScript doesn't scream at you when you go to start your app.

```
import { Component,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'ssContent',
  templateUrl: 'app/content/content.html',
})
export class ContentComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    $.getScript('../js/myjsfile.js');
  }
}
```

**Update**
Actually in my scenario the OnInit lifecycle event worked better because it prevented the script from loading after the views were loaded, which was the case with ngAfterViewInit, and that cause the view to show incorrect element positions prior to the script loading.

```
ngOnInit() {
    $.getScript('../js/mimity.js');
  }
```

Comment: I get `Cannot find name '$'.` when I try to follow this example?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code I think you need the jQuery typings, how about giving `npm install @types/jquery -D` a shot? :D

Answer (score 8):

the accepted answer is not correct, and it makes no sens to accept it considering the question

ngAfterViewInit will trigger when the DOM is ready

whine ngOnInit will trigger when the page component is only starting to be created

Comment: Try to be very clear only about your solution in your answer and if you think some answer is not correct, consider commenting on that question instead.

Comment: no Problem, just try to make your answer more clear to help more people. with a minimalist code example.

Comment: your answer is what i needed and came looking into, thanks

Answer (score 4):

In order to use jQuery inside Angular only declare the $ as following: 
**declare var $: any;**

Comment: where do you put this?

Comment: @DanChase you can place it after the imports of the libraries in the class

Comment: take a look for this nice article for uncluding jquery usinng angular-cli:
https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176

Answer (score 0):

In your **main.ts** file bootstrap after  DOMContentLoaded so angular will load when DOM is fully loaded.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```