# In Angular2+, how to detect template changes?

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular, if I want to add a DOM element called `elem1` dynamically and want to run some method to make `elem1` for example draggable, how can I determine that the DOM element is ready for use? Because if I run the `draggable` method instantly after the DOM element adding function, it may doesn't work some times.

I tried `OnChanges` in ng but it seems this only works for `@Input` rather than DOM.

So I am now using jQuery.ready() function but I wonder if there is more elegant way in Angular.

Comment: Have you tried `ngAfterViewInit()` (https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)?

Comment: @John I want to change elements after the `AfterViewInit` hook

Answer (score 0):

You must use @ViewChild decorator and access the element inside ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook.

Like this:

ts file

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myEl') el: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // element is ready for use
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

html file

```
<div #myEl></div>
```

Comment: I need to add some elements after `ngAfterViewInit()` works

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` from this answer [Angular2 equivalent of $document.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547127/angular2-equivalent-of-document-ready)

But imagine a situation where your components are added dynamically during working with the page. I assume that your `makeDraggable` function is making some element `<div data-draggable="true"></div>` "draggable" but the problem is that you try to do it once.

Maybe you need to use event delegation and listen to `click` event on `body`, look at `event.target.dataset.draggable` property and if it's `true` - apply your `makeDraggable` function here. This is a very common way to handle components creation time of which you're not aware about.

Comment: I want to change elements after the AfterViewInit hook