# unable to show bootstrap carousel data correctly using angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

here i am displaying the data in bootstrap carousel here for each slide i am displaying 3 images and in the last slide i am displaying only 2 images there it is showing how can i perform loop and continue the slide with out showing empty while applying dynamic data i unable to perform the same task below is the code which i performed in html

.html code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <h1>Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**.css**
/* override position and transform in 3.3.x */

```
.carousel-inner .item.left.active {
  transform: translateX(-33%);
}
.carousel-inner .item.right.active {
  transform: translateX(33%);
}

.carousel-inner .item.next {
  transform: translateX(33%)
}
.carousel-inner .item.prev {
  transform: translateX(-33%)
}

.carousel-inner .item.right,
.carousel-inner .item.left { 
  transform: translateX(0);
}


.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
```

**.js code:**

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547127/angular2-equivalent-of-document-ready might be useful

Comment: i can implent in angular but result i am not getting

Comment: Is your jquery even working? If not then checkout this link first - [Using jQuery in Angular](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176)

Comment: i installed jquery using npm and later declared variable for $ & jquery also it is working

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using a library such as [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) or [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/).
Keep in mind that these libraries do not support animations yet. This way you can avoid using `jQuery`, and saves you from writing a bunch of code.